# Get a list of all files in images folder of Visual Studio Project solution

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, file, c#-4.0, dynamic

I want to loop over all the files in the images folder of my solution.

```
HtmlGenericControl iframe;
foreach (var item in Directory.GetFiles(ResolveClientUrl("~/Images")))
{
   //images will be loaded dynamically into iframes here.
}
```

I also tried with this `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` but i am not able to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You did not write exactly, what the problem is. 
I can only GUESS that you do not receive any file, but no Exception, either. If that is the case:

Did you change the files property to "Copy always" or "copy when newer"?

Comment: Directory is starts from loaction c:/somepath, i want it to check files on my solution only

Comment: Then, the file properties is where to check. Default is "Do not copy". You have to change that setting

Answer (score 0):

```
 String virtualPath = Server.MapPath("~");
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(virtualPath);
DirectoryInfo[] subFolders = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();
```

// This will give you all the folders

```
foreach (DirectoryInfo subFolder in subFolders)
{
    if(subFolder=="images")
      {
        FileInfo[] fileInfo = subFolder.GetFiles();
      }
}
```

Try this.. This will work